# Rename result property in normalizr

Tags: javascript, normalizr

Given data like:

```
{
  id: 1,
  ownerName: 'bob',
  devices: [
    {
      id: 2
    },
    {
      id: 3
    }
  ]
}
```

how would I convert it to the following object

```
{
  result: 1,
  entities: {
    owners: {
      1: {
        id: 1,
        ownerName: 'bob',
        deviceIds: [2, 3]
      }
    },
    devices: {
      2: {
        id: 2
      },
      3: {
        id: 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

using normalizr? I can't figure out how to change `devices` to `deviceIds` in the returned result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Process Strategy for this. It allows you to manipulate your data before it is processed. Simply return a copy of your object with the keys changed from the `processStrategy()` method.

```
const Device = schema.Entity('devices');

const Owner = schema.Entity(
    'owners',
    {
        deviceIds: [ Device ]
    },
    {
        processStrategy: value => ({
            id: value.id,
            ownerName: value.ownerName,
            deviceIds: value.devices
        })
    }
);
```